# Getting PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process during scikitlearn GridSearchCV

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, grid-search, joblib, gridsearchcv

Getting `PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process` during `GridSearchCV` functionality of `scikit-learn`.

**Here is my script:**

```
df = pd.read_csv(CSV_FILE_PATH, sep=',', header=0)

df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=random_state)
X_train, y_train = df_train.iloc[:, 1:-1], df_train.iloc[:, -1]
X_test, y_test = df_test.iloc[:, 1:-1], df_test.iloc[:, -1]

X_train = np.reshape(X_train.values, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test.values, (X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1]))

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model_optimizer, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)

param_grid = dict(optimizer=['adadelta', 'sgd', 'adam'])

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=3)
grid_result = grid.fit(X_test, to_categorical(y_test))
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

**Error stacktrace:**

```
D:\.virtualenvs\signal_processing_keras-0Sqytsnt\lib\site-packages\joblib\disk.py:122: UserWarning: Unable to delete folder C:\Users\talha\AppData\Local\Temp\joblib_memmapping_folder_9640_7658187734 after 5 tentatives.
  .format(folder_path, RM_SUBDIRS_N_RETRY))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\signal_processing_keras-0Sqytsnt\lib\site-packages\joblib\disk.py", line 115, in delete_folder
    shutil.rmtree(folder_path, False, None)
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\signal_processing_keras-0Sqytsnt\lib\shutil.py", line 516, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\signal_processing_keras-0Sqytsnt\lib\shutil.py", line 400, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "D:\.virtualenvs\signal_processing_keras-0Sqytsnt\lib\shutil.py", line 398, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\talha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\joblib_memmapping_folder_9640_7658187734\\9640-1516123463368-0106d247f5d8461b9e06e246788ccb51.pkl'
D:\.virtualenvs\signal_processing_keras-0Sqytsnt\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py:409: UserWarning: Failed to clean temporary folder: C:\Users\talha\AppData\Local\Temp\joblib_memmapping_folder_9640_7658187734
  .format(pool_folder))
```

**Software Stack:**

```
System:
    python: 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
executable: D:\.virtualenvs\signal_processing_keras-0Sqytsnt\Scripts\python.exe
   machine: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0

Python deps:
       pip: 19.3.1
setuptools: 41.6.0
   sklearn: 0.21.3
     numpy: 1.17.4
     scipy: 1.3.2
    Cython: None
    pandas: 0.25.3
Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
NumPy 1.17.4
SciPy 1.3.2
Scikit-Learn 0.21.3
```

Comment: Might be useful: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12546

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, have already looked at the comments posted there. @BramVanroy

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem attempting to perform logistic regression with scikit-learn.  Updating the packages "joblib" and "scikit-learn" fixed it for me:

```
pip install --upgrade joblib scikit-learn
```